# Setting the ACL when creating a new database via JS in XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am creating a new database using JS from an action button. The following sequence happens:

- When the database is created the -default- access is set to Manager which it has to be.
- I then create several aclEntries. The first entry created for the current user and set them as a type person and having Manager rights
- I then create several other entries with varying right and save the ACL.

If I open the Db the ACL looks and acts correctly except the -default- has an access level of Manager.

So I tried change my code to set the access level for -default- to Author in various ways, **all** resulting in an exception:

- Change -default- to Author and save
- First save the ACL as above, then change the -default- entry and save
- create the ACL object newly using `var newACL = db.getACL()`, change and try to save

It seems that it does not recognize me as a manger in the ACL.

Q: How do I change the -default- access away from manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get a good default ACL is using a template database. All entries in your template that come in square brackets are copied into the new database as ACL entries.

So in your template you would have

- `[-Default-]=Author` and `[Anonymous]=No Access` which results in
- `-Default-=Author` and `Anonymous=No Access` in the new DB

**Update**
Easier that it looks. You need to make sure to get the entries right...
Use this function:

```
function makeDB(dbName) {
   var server = database.getServer();
   var you = @UserName();
   var dbDir = session.getDbDirectory(server);
   var db = dbDir.createDatabase(dbName);
   var acl = db.getACL();
   acl.createACLEntry(you,6);
   if (server != "" && server != you) {
      acl.createACLEntry(server,6);
   }   
   var def = acl.getEntry("-Default-");
   def.setLevel(3);
   acl.save();
}
```

Then you call the function using:

```
makeDB("someFancyDBName");
```

In the function we make sure that you, who runs the script and the server where it runs are both in the ACL as managers (including the case of a local database, where in the Notes client the server is empty and in the web preview would be your user name).

Works like a charm. If it doesn't work for you, there are a few things to check:

- Does it work on local (no server involved)?
- Do you have errors on the console?
- What access level do you have in the server **ECL**
- Check the "max Internet access" of the database

**The previous answer** (obsolete):

Other than that it is a little trickier...

You create the new database:

```
   var db:Database = [... whatever you have todo here ...];
   var acl:Acl = db.getAcl();
   // Do whatever you do, don't touch -Default-
   acl.save();
   acl.recycle();
   var dbURL = db.getUrl(); // <-- off my head might be slightly different name
   db.recycle();

   // Now the real work
   var db2 = session.evaluate(dbUrl);
   var acl2 = db2.getAcl();

   // Change default here;
```

Typed off my head, contains typos.

This should work. Let us know how it goes

Comment: The problem is that using a template really wont work in this situation. I need to work with the ACL directly. I just tried another option. After adding myself as an ACL entry with Manager Rights I saved the ACL and db.recycle. I then opened the database var newDB = etc. and retrieved the ACL which showed the default and myself as Managers. I changed the -default- to Author and tried saving the ACL and it failed again. If I comment out the code to change the -default- to author everything works as I would expect it but leaves the DB with -default- = Manager which I can't leave it at.

Comment: I added recycle of the vars acl aclEntry and DB, then

Comment: I added recycle of the vars acl aclEntry and DB, then 
var DB2:NotesDatabase = dir.openDatabase(filePath + fileName);
var acl2:NotesACL = targetDB2.getACL();
var aclEntry2:NotesACLEntry = acl2.getEntry("-default-");
then set the aclEntry2.setLevel(3) plus some other entries - these all seem to have worked until I tries acl2.save() and it failed and I got an exception error. Opening the Db by the dbURL wouldn't work but I think that is a problem with my server as I have tried that on this server before and it did not work, but opening the DB to a new var should do the same thing.

Comment: You need to sort out the URL issue. Most likely a connection document can help you there (or a hosts/DNS entry for the short name)

Comment: That worked like a charm. I added the entry for the server into my existing code and it all works perfect. So even though I have Manager access it does not make any difference, it needs the server to have Manager access. I guess because this is running SSJS that it is running with the server ID and there for the server access rights. To begin with it gets Manager rights from the default, if there is no explicit entry for the server in the ACL then you can not change the default because then there would be no Manager in the ACL.

Comment: Glad to be of service :-)